# Creating new Kafka Producer object for every request

Tags: java, apache-kafka, message-queue

I am developing a rest service which will publish event to kafka (using java client) on the basic of topic, different topic can have different no. of brokers.
I'm creating Producer for each and every request to send message into Kafka. I feel this is inefficient and can be achieved in more manageable by maintaining a pool of producers, will it really help? Please provide suggestions.

Comment: Which version of Kafka do you use? It should be possible to write to different topics using a single producer: https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a single producer and write to different topics (https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html). The class `ProducerRecord` offers a constructor that allows to specify the topic a record should be written to (https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerRecord.html)

```java
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:4242");
props.put("acks", "all");
props.put("retries", 0);
props.put("batch.size", 16384);
props.put("linger.ms", 1);
props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("my-topic", Integer.toString(i), Integer.toString(i)));

producer.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but what if the list of servers are different for each topic?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly. If you have single Kafka cluster with many brokers, the ownership of topic (partitions) and servers in managed by Kafka internally. You do not need to worry about it. Only specify some of your brokers in "bootstrap.servers" (see https://kafka.apache.org/090/documentation.html#producerconfigs)

Comment: This does not really answer the question whether it is a good idea to instantiate a new producer for each REST request or have a single one via CDI injection for example.

Comment: The implicit answer is, that it is not recommended to create a new producer each time, but to use a single instance.